# Custom Notification update on click

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-remoteview

I am using custum notifiation by creating a layout.I want ot change the background of ImageView in custom notification layout when i click that image in notification..
I want to do this without re creating the whole notification, just change the image ..